# why internal server error ?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

POST http://localhost:3000/basicUser/saveUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError

i get a object with date here , obj : [name: "sourav", phone: "1111111"]

action.js

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
export function saveBasicUser(obj) {
  console.log("console log from actions...........")
  console.log(obj)
  return (dispatch) => {

    return axios.post('/basicUser/saveUser', {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      obj: obj 
  }).then(function (res) {

  console.log(" response from action")
  console.log( res)
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(" err")
    console.log( err)
  })
 }
}
```

server.js

```
 var basicController = require('./controllers/basicController');

 app.post('/basicUser/saveUser', basicController.savebasicUser);
```

controller file

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var BasicUser = require('../models/basicUser');

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
exports.savebasicUser = function(req, res) {
console.log("-------------req from controller-----")
console.log(req)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/610),

you can try to print the error that you are receiving by using `console.log(error.response.data);` in your *action.js*